# What are my problems with my VMWare runlevel setup?

Tags: init, debian, rc

I recently upgraded to Debian Wheezy (7) and had to upgrade VMWare Player along with that since the version I had didn't like the 3.2 kernel.

However, I notice that the kernel modules aren't starting for VMWare (such as `vmmon`, `vmnet` and `vmci`) and, because of that, the virtual machines complain bitterly when I try to start them.

If I start the modules manually with `modprobe`, it works fine, at least until the next boot where they've disappeared again.

It also works fine if I manually run `/etc/init.d/vmware start` beforehand, and it's this solution I have as a workaround, starting them from a script before it calls the `vmplayer` executable.

I've noticed in the `rcX.d` directories (2, 3 and 5) that there is a `K01vmware` script but no `Snn` ones to be found and I believe this is what's causing it to not start. However, when I create a `Snn` link in `rc2.d` (and 2 is the correct runlevel for my system according to the `runlevel` command returning `N 2`), it still doesn't start.

First off, is there any way that a `rc` service could run other than via the `S/K` scripts in `rcX.d`? It appears from my experience that it will never start the service because there's no `Snn` link to do so.

Secondly, why would this *still* not work even when I *create* a `Snn` entry in `rc2.d`?

The top of the `/etc/init.d/vmware` script follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Copyright 1998-2008 VMware, Inc.  All rights reserved.
#
# This script manages the services needed to run VMware software.
#

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vmware
# Required-Start: $network $syslog
# Required-Stop: $network $syslog
# X-Start-Before:
# X-Stop-After:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4
# Default-Stop: 0 6
# Short-Description: This service starts and stops VMware services
### END INIT INFO
```

The list of all `rc` scripts with `vm` in them is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Mar 20  2012 rc2.d/K01vmware -> ../init.d/vmware
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May  6 19:09 rc2.d/K01vmware-USBArbitrator -> ../init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 May  6 19:55 rc2.d/S49vmware -> ../init.d/vmware
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 May  6 16:18 rc2.d/S50vmware-USBArbitrator -> /etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Mar 20  2012 rc3.d/K01vmware -> ../init.d/vmware
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May  6 19:09 rc3.d/K01vmware-USBArbitrator -> ../init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 May  6 16:18 rc3.d/S50vmware-USBArbitrator -> /etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Mar 20  2012 rc5.d/K01vmware -> ../init.d/vmware
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May  6 19:09 rc5.d/K01vmware-USBArbitrator -> ../init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 May  6 16:18 rc5.d/S50vmware-USBArbitrator -> /etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator
```

The `rc2.d/S49` one is the one I created which still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

#### First question

> First off, is there any way that a rc service could run other than via
>   the S/K scripts in rcX.d? It appears from my experience that it will
>   never start the service because there's no Snn link to do so.

start/stop scripts can be run from `/etc/rc.local` like so: `/etc/init.d/vmware start`, for example. Not recommended but they can be run from there.

#### Second question

I'd put some logger messages in the start/stop script so you can see what's going on in `/var/log/syslog`.

Typically the messages are like this:

```
logger "here I am"
```